# adb connect the same device twice (or more)

Tags: android, adb

If I have an emulated Android device running on a network and it is accessible via `adb`, is it possible for multiple users to `adb connect` the same endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Tt should be. I've done this with two different users on Linux having shell sessions on the same physical device simultaneously. However, it may not be a good idea:

- Both sessions will be running as the same user account on your emulator, "shell" for shell sessions.
- They have to share the available memory, because Android does not do swapping.